# Pressing Ctrl + C on computer.keyboard

Tags: datagridview, clipboard, keyboard-events

So i am building a tool which is called "**Clipboard History**"

My target is, when i copy something from anywhere(web, pc text etc) i want to add my.computer.clipboard to datagridview.

everything is fine so i just need a command or something that recognizing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> (in pckeyboard, not only form active) and do  once (Form1.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(DateAndTime.Now, Clipboard.GetText)

```
    Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    Dim keydata As Keys
    If My.Computer.Keyboard.CtrlKeyDown AndAlso keydata.C Then
        Form1.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(DateAndTime.Now, Clipboard.GetText)

    End If
End Sub
```

thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard .Net library that I know of that can accomplish what you want.  By using the Windows API function [AddClipboardFormatListener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649033(v=vs.85).aspx) you can receive notification of items placed on the ClipBoard.

AddClipboardFormatListener requires a Window handle to which to send the notification.  I use a class derived from [System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow(v=vs.110).aspx) to listen for the [WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649021%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  This class defined below, expose an `Event` named ClipBoardDataAvailable that can be subscribed too and it the passed argument is a [DataObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dataobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) that can be used to retrieve the Clipboard contents.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class ClipboardListener : Inherits NativeWindow
    Implements IDisposable
    Public Event ClipBoardDataAvailable(data As DataObject)

    Public Sub New()
        Me.CreateHandle(New CreateParams())
        AddClipboardFormatListener(Me.Handle)
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub DestroyHandle()
        Me.Dispose()
        MyBase.DestroyHandle()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        Const WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE As Int32 = &H31D
        If m.Msg = WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE Then
            Dim data As DataObject = CType(Clipboard.GetDataObject, DataObject)
            RaiseEvent ClipBoardDataAvailable(data)
        End If
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Public Shared Function AddClipboardFormatListener(hWnd As IntPtr) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Public Shared Function RemoveClipboardFormatListener(hWnd As IntPtr) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
    End Function

#Region "IDisposable Support"
    Private disposedValue As Boolean ' To detect redundant calls

    ' IDisposable
    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
        If Not Me.disposedValue Then
            RemoveClipboardFormatListener(Me.Handle)
        End If
        Me.disposedValue = True
    End Sub

    ' TODO: override Finalize() only if Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean) above has code to free unmanaged resources.
    Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
         ' Do not change this code.  Put cleanup code in Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean) above.
         Dispose(False)
         MyBase.Finalize()
    End Sub

    ' This code added by Visual Basic to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        ' Do not change this code.  Put cleanup code in Dispose(disposing As Boolean) above.
        Dispose(True)
        GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    End Sub
#End Region

End Class
```

Example Usage:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private WithEvents listener As New ClipboardListener

    Private Sub listener_ClipBoardDataAvailable(data As DataObject) Handles listener.ClipBoardDataAvailable
        If data.ContainsText Then Debug.Print(data.GetText)
    End Sub
End Class
```